# insert data into a table - primary key constraint

Tags: php, mysql

I have a db table created like this

```
CREATE TABLE products(id INT,   
                      name varchar(32),   
                      PRIMARY KEY(id,name),   
                      quantity int,   
                      avail varchar(5) );
```

If I use the following command on the command prompt, the value is inserted properly:

```
INSERT INTO products(name,quantity,avail) VALUES('stuffed bear doll',100,'OF_ST');
```

although the id is duplicated

but when I leave it inside the function like this

```
$query=sprintf("INSERT INTO products(name,quantity,avail) VALUES('%s',%d,'%s');",
                   $name,
                   $quan,
                   $avail);

mysql_query($query);
```

then there is no insertion done at all.

Comment: echo mysql_error() to know the error

Comment: `mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());` and tell us what you get.

Comment: make sure to auto increment id

Comment: `:Duplicate entry '0-somename' for key 'PRIMARY'`

Comment: Check Cold Told's response. A Primary key should be AUTO_INCREMENT.

Comment: @FluffyKitten: Upvoted both: the comment and your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needed to set auto_increment on the id field in your create table syntax. You can edit the column to add it.

Also, if $quan is not valid your SQL syntax will give you an error. Put quotes around it: `VALUES('%s','%d','%s')`

Answer (score 0):

there is no problem in Your query but i think value of `name field is duplicate`. As your table structure `id-name is primary` mean two rows can not have same value of both `id` and `name` field. One time one field value can be same but not for both. And here in your table value of `id` field is always `0` so if in any row value of `name` field repeat it will not insert that row. And please make `id` as primary and auto increment so it will be better.

thanks

Comment: I think that the only problem his query has is that the id field is not auto-increment.

Comment: @verisimilitude : hi yes due to id is not auto incremented when value for name field is repeat it not take input because combination of id and name is primary. If we keep name value different then it will take input or add auto increment of id it will be work